# Replace <div id="content"> across entire store

Tags: woocommerce

I'm on a quest to remove the `<div id="content"><div class="woocommerce">` wrapping container and replace it with more appropriate tag which matches the rest of my site.

I first tried actions:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 20); 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 20); 

function WOO_before_main_content( $woocommerce_output_content_wrapper ) { 
    echo '<main class="woocommerce">';
}
function WOO_after_main_content( $woocommerce_output_content_wrapper ) { 
    echo '</main>';
}

// Use <main> instead, much better.
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'WOO_after_main_content', 5);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content',  'WOO_before_main_content', 5);
```

This seems to work on some pages (like a category or product page) but other pages like account/login and cart are left untouched.

I then tried copying the template files into my theme and updating the HTML there.

```
woocommerce/global/wrapper-start.php
woocommerce/global/wrapper-end.php
```

Again, same result. Any idea why I'm not able to control the wrapper globally across my entire store?

**UPDATE**

In doing some more research, the [hook guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) lists `woocommerce_before_main_content` action as only called by `archive-product.php, single-product.php`. So I guess not every page? This slightly confuses me as every post online says to use it to edit the wrapping HTML element. Perhaps something recently changed?

Searching the entire Woocommerce plugin directory, `global/wrapper-start.php` is the only thing that contains `id="content"`, so it must be coming from there. Again, attempts at overriding this template to my theme's *woocommerce/global/wrapper-start.php* do not work.

So tracking even farther back, the `woocommerce_output_content_wrapper()` function in `wc-template-functions.php` is the only thing which loads wrapper-start template. I have tried defining this ahead of Woocommerce in my functions.php file and it also doesn't work.

I have to be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove an action with the same priority as what it is added as.  In your code you are using 20 as the priority but WooCommerce adds it as 10.

```
// First remove default wrapper
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

// Then add new wrappers
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
  echo '<main class="woocommerce">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
  echo '</main>';
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I tried changing the priorities and it still only applies to some pages and not all. I've also added some more details to the main topic post about additional research I have done.

Comment: Which pages does the original markup still appear on?

Comment: Cart, Checkout, Account (Basically anything other then product category or single).